# Como utilizar if/else ou For loops em R?

Tags: r

Escrevi a seguinte função para abrir um arquivo qualquer, não necessariamente DNASeq. Na prática eu consigo abrir um arquivo com qualquer outro nome, só nomeei a variável de DNASeq para conseguir construir a função.

```
openfasta<-function(DNAseq){
  DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:")
  readLines(DNASeq)
```

Agora preciso que, ao tentar aplicar a função, caso o arquivo não seja encontrado retorne um aviso (Este arquivo não existe, como por exemplo utilizando `cat`) e que a função continue me pedindo o nome desse arquivo até que eu forneça (`DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:")`). Acredito que seja possível utilizando if/else e loops, tentei o seguinte código mas não funcionou.

```
openfasta<-function(DNAseq){
  DNASeq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:")
  if (DNAseq = TRUE){
           readLines(DNASeq)
  } else {
       print("No such file")
       readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:")
  }
}
```

Comment: `DNAseq = TRUE` é um erro de sintaxe. O operador de igualdade é `==`

Comment: Além do que o @TomásBarcellos disse, se `DNAseq` é igual a `TRUE` não vale a pena testar a igualdade, a variável já é um valor lógico.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui vai uma maneira, com um ciclo `while`. E `message` em vez de `print`.

```
openfasta <- function(DNAseq){
  while(!file.exists(DNAseq)){
    msg <- paste0("cannot open file '", DNAseq, "': No such file or directory\n")
    message(msg)
    DNAseq <- readline(prompt = "Enter the .fasta file name:")
  }
  readLines(DNAseq)
}
```